# ServiceNow REST API - How do I make a query fail if it is invalid when using REST?

Tags: rest, api, postman, servicenow

ServiceNow REST API - How do I make a query fail if it is invalid when using REST e.g. using Postman?

This article states that you can provide a parameter when using glide, but it is not clear how you would achieve the same result when querying the API directly:

https://developer.servicenow.com/app.do#!/rest_api_doc?v=london&id=r_TableAPI-GET

Answer (score 1):

The system property glide.invalid_query.returns_no_rows does not make a query fail. It makes it return zero rows if there is an invalid parameter. If the property is false then invalid parameters will be ignored. It the property is true then invalid parameters will cause the query to return zero rows. Since it is a global system property, it will affect all queries whether they be Glide or Web Services.

Comment: To add to this: this is not problem of the SNOW REST Api, it is system wide. If you form a malformed URL to your instance or create malformed encoded query in a GlideRecord, it will not throw an error or exception.

Comment: Please could you provide clarification of how to send that parameter using a REST call (e.g. in Postman)?

Comment: **glide.invalid_query.returns_no_rows** is a system property. It is global. It cannot be specified as a REST parameter.